# How to Chage textbox value based on Form Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

For Example:

```
<form id="test1">
   <input type="text" name="test_input">
</form>

<form id="test2">
    <input type="text" name="test_input">
</form>
```

The above code mentioned same name for both text box. actually I want to change first form text box value.

```
$('input[name=test_input][form=test1]').val("Test Input");
```

How can i change the value. Please help me to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

`#test1` selects the elements which have id `test`

```js
$('#test1 input[name=test_input]').val("Test Input");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test1">
  <input type="text" name="test_input">
</form>

<form id="test2">
  <input type="text" name="test_input">
</form>
```

or using **[`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)**

```js
$('input[name=test_input]').eq(0).val("Test Input");
// $('input[name=test_input]:eq(0)').val("Test Input");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="test1">
  <input type="text" name="test_input">
</form>

<form id="test2">
  <input type="text" name="test_input">
</form>
```